# jquery multiselect :reload jquery multiselect with other drop down values if last option is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I refresh jquery multiselect when the last option is selected with new values? Like I have the below options in my multiselect:

```
<select id="positions" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="0">Programmer</option>
    <option value="1">Tester</option>
    <option value="2">Manager</option>
    <option value="3">Admin</option>
    <option value="4">Load all other</option>    
</select>
```

If the user selects the "load all other" option from the multiselect box, then this multiselect should be reinitialized with different values.

```
<select id="positions2" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="0">test1</option>
    <option value="1">test2</option>
    <option value="2">test3</option>
    <option value="3">test4</option>    
</select>
```

Above is the resultant options that the multiselect will have after selecting load all other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. Off the top of my head I would use the `html` function. Set an id to the option that needs to clicked and add an event handler to it. Would you like me to write the code for you?

**UPDATE**

This will replace the code in the first select. If you simply want to hide it and add a new select element then use the show/hide function. **Dont forget to add `id="option"` attribute to the option that needs to be clicked.**

**UPDATE** - I have added comments to help you understand what the script is doing

```
// Set the click event of the option (change '#option' to the options id)
$('#option').click(function(){
    // Alter the HTML content of the select
    $('#positions').html('<option value="0">test1</option><option value="1">test2</option><option value="2">test3</option><option value="3">test4</option>');
});
```

Comment: Do you want the other options to come back, or do you want it to simply replace the old options with the new ones?